# proper usage of the pre-increment operator in combination with the pointer dereference operator

Tags: c, operators, increment, dereference

I just wrote the following line of code:

```
if (++(data_ptr->count) > threshold) { /*...*/ } // example 1
```

My intent is to increment the `count` variable within the data structure that `data_ptr` points to before making the comparison to `threshold`, and this line of code works.

If I had instead wanted to increment `data_ptr` before making the comparison, I would have written this:

```
if ((++data_ptr)->count > threshold) { /*...*/ } // example 2
```

Out of curiosity, I also tried this line of code:

```
if (++data_ptr->count > threshold) { /*...*/ } // example 3
```

And found that it behaves exactly the same as the first one.

**First question:** *Why* does example #3 work the same as example #1? Is it a matter of operator precendence? Something in the standard? I had to write a quick test program becuase the answer was not obvious to me.

**Second question:** Should I write this `if` statement differently? I could perform the increment first, on its own line, and *then* test the condition in order to avoid any possible confusion. Is this necessary, or are the first two examples obvious enough on their own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Precedence

2) Preference

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a question of operator precedence. The arrow operator [has higher precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) than the increment operator.

To answer your second question, I would generally separate this type of construct out into two separate statements:

```
++(data_ptr->count);
if(data_ptr->count > threshold) { /*...*/ }
```

This emphasizes what is going on and eliminates possible confusion. However, this is probably a question of preference.

Answer (score 5):

1. Operator precedence dictates the behaviour you observed.
2. It wouldn't hurt much if you separated the increment from the comparison in this example, but sometimes you want to have a condition with increment in the middle of a sequence of conditions, and then trying to separate the increment from the test can hurt the readability of the code by introducing nesting that would otherwise be unnecessary.

For example:

```
if (...1...)
    ...2...
else if (++data_ptr->count > threshold)
    ...3...
else
    ...4...
```

Versus:

```
if (...1...)
    ...2...
else
{
    ++data_ptr->count;
    if (data_ptr->count > threshold)
        ...3...
    else
        ...4...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The -> operator binds tighter than ++.
2. They're both well-defined and I think they're easy to read. Things would only get dodgy if you had additional references to data_ptr in the same expression.